# cant deploy vue app in docker with parcel

Tags: vue.js, parcel

Not able to load vue in docker container, using parcel.

Vue is not loaded, and vue devtools cant find vue. All files seems to be in devtools/sources.

Its working outside of docker with npm run dev.

JS error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
at vue.common.prod.js:6

Dockerfile:

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app 
COPY package.json /app
RUN apk add --update npm
RUN apk add util-linux
ENV FONTAWESOME_NPM_AUTH_TOKEN XXXXX
COPY .npmrc /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm audit fix
COPY src/. /app/src
COPY index.html /app
RUN npm run production

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "alias": {
    "vue": "/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.common.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel index.html",
    "production": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.15.1",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "faker": "^5.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^2.3.4",
    "vue-router": "^3.4.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/component-compiler-utils": "^3.2.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.4",
    "sass": "^1.32.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.12"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can probably get your dev server going.

I think parcel's default port is 1234. So you need to tell it to be on port 80. Also hot-reloading wont work unless you specify and expose the ws port that it
Change your package parcel run command like so.

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "parcel index.html -p 80 --hmr-port 33333",
  },
}
```

Then add this to your Dockerfile

```
...
EXPOSE 33333
```

That should allow parcel to connect to the parcel dev server